# i get weird Result when i use layout_width=0 in a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to build a layout of a  **ViewHolder** that looks like picture 1 for a **RecyclerView** but instead i get some weird result, it's a project in bignerdranch 3rd version of android books and i'm sure i'm doing everything same as the book.[the expected View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfvPn.jpg)

but instead the `layout` looks like [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnt6s.jpg)

and this is the `xml` code for this layout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Crime Title"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/crime_solved"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Crime Date"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/crime_solved"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_title" />




    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_solved" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `layout_width = 0`, you should use additional property to your Views: `android:layout_weight="1"` that indicates the the relative width of views in parent layout. Add iy in each kid view, i think it will solve your problem.
And i don't understand why you use ConstraintLayout in such simple case, i think LinearLayout fits better here.

Answer (score 0):

as you are new to android and to constraint layout ....

Here the guideline for naming convention we should follow for a long run in android . https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md

As i can see hard coded text in your view , which is consider as bad practice in android . Always put your string in string file and your dimens (which is also hard code ) in dimens file . res < values < dimens .

And one surprised me alot is , why are you using orientation in constraint layout ?? Anyways i tried your view and hope this will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white_50"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/crime_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="Crime Title"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/crime_solved"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/crime_date"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Crime Date"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/crime_title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/crime_title"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_title" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crime_title"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_date"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_solved" />
```

I have slight changes in the view , and removed some unnecessary code .In case of any doubt please let me know .